# How do I import a java classname with a dollar sign ($), or refer to a field or method with one, in Jython?

Tags: java, scala, jython

Naive attempts fail: e.g.

```
from mypackage import SomeClass$
```

gives

> javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at character '$' in  at line number 1

This question is unrelated to java nested classes, which are easily importable in Jython.

Such a class is for example the `scala.Predef$` class, which one can then access with `Predef$.foobar`.

How can I achieve this import?

Comment: Do you have an example of the class you are importing? is it an inner class perchance? Normally classes container $ are internal to some thing or other, I'm concerned you have an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: I'm trying to access the scala.Predef$ class, usually importable in java via "import scala.Predef$;" then referrable to via "Predef$.<whatever>"

Comment: Holy Polyglot Batman.

Comment: inner classes have the `$` because of the compiler mangling the namespace. you should not have to use the `$`

Comment: This is unrelated to inner classes. $ is a legal part of a java class identifier, which as far as I can tell, Jython does not support importing.

Comment: I asked in #jython on freenet, _grey(non op) suggested filing a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using Java Reflection like this:

```
from java.lang import Class

person = Class.forName("full.path.to.Person$").getField("MODULE$").get(None)
```

It's not pretty but it works. It might be nicer to use the Scala reflection API if that's available.