# Accessing a Scala singleton object from Jython

Tags: scala, jython

I'm working in Python and trying to call some Java / Scala libraries using Jython. One Scala library I'm using has singleton objects, which can be called from Java like this: (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284158/1359626))

```
Person$.MODULE$
```

I can't do this in my code because the $ sign is a syntax error in Python:

```
person = Person.MODULE$.apply()
                     ^
SyntaxError: no viable alternative at character '$'
```

How can I access this object from Python / Jython?

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623470/how-do-i-import-a-java-classname-with-a-dollar-sign-or-refer-to-a-field-or

Comment: @JoelBerkeley thanks for linking to that - I'm wondering whether there's another way of accessing a singleton object that doesn't involve any dollar signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using reflection. The name of the class with the $ sign is provided as a string literal.

```
from java.lang import Class

person = Class.forName("full.path.to.Person$").getField("MODULE$").get(None)
```